# How does the Component ModalItem knows the value of "num" when state changes and code runs again?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const faqs = [
  {
    title: "Where are these chairs assembled?",
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Accusantium, quaerat temporibus quas dolore provident nisi ut aliquid ratione beatae sequi aspernatur veniam repellendus.",
  },
  {
    title: "How long do I have to return my chair?",
    text: "Pariatur recusandae dignissimos fuga voluptas unde optio nesciunt commodi beatae, explicabo natus.",
  },
  {
    title: "Do you ship to countries outside the EU?",
    text: "Excepturi velit laborum, perspiciatis nemo perferendis reiciendis aliquam possimus dolor sed! Dolore laborum ducimus veritatis facere molestias!",
  },
];

export default function App() {
  return <Modal data={faqs} />;
}

function Modal({ data }) {
  const [currOpen, setCurrOpen] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div className="content">
      <QuestionTitle className="knowelege">
        Check Your React Knowelege!
      </QuestionTitle>

      {data.map((question, index) => (
        <ModalItem
          num={index}
          title={question.title}
          text={question.text}
          key={index}
          currOpen={currOpen}
          onCurrOpen={setCurrOpen}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

function ModalItem({ num, title, text, currOpen, onCurrOpen }) {
  const isOpen = num === currOpen;

  function handleModal() {
    onCurrOpen(num);
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex" onClick={handleModal}>
      <span className="number">0{num + 1}</span>
      <QuestionTitle className="title">{title}</QuestionTitle>
      <span className="icon">{isOpen ? "-" : "+"}</span>
      {isOpen ? <Answer>{text}</Answer> : false}
    </div>
  );
}

function Answer({ children }) {
  return <p className="hidden-text">{children}</p>;
}

function QuestionTitle({ className, children }) {
  return <h1 className={className ? className : ""}>{children}</h1>;
}
```

when this code gets executed and whole UI is rendered through map function, then on later point a click happens on an el.

Then at that point how the handleModal event listener function knows the value of num as it needs to change the state of currOpen value. Because, when an event happens only the function attached to event listener would run.

so at that point, how does the handleModal function knows the value of num

and also this ModalItem Component is running three times because of map method, does that mean all the code and function inside ModalItem Component would run three times and would take space in memory in three different location???

Comment: `onCurrOpen` runs `setCurrOpen` which triggers a rerender of the `Modal` component and all of its children. Yes, all the code in the functions runs multiple times. Every time a state is changed the variables are created etc. Don't worry about it, browsers are fast and garbage collector clear unused data

Comment: Also worth noting the re-render is not a physical one, React will compare the props so updates are actually partial / optimized.

Comment: so ModalItem Component runs three times, so three different ModalItem function is created and they are stored in three different location in memory, with each it's own variables. Then also event Listerner function is also created three times, within ModalItem function scope and then when the event listner is executed, it takes value of num from it's own scope??

Comment: When you click a button a `Modal` function is called which then causes three `ModalItem` functions to get called with new values passed. Take a look what happens in the console https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-nobel-v93r8d?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Pretty much..  When I first started using React, the best way I would describe the way you code, is a bit like a game engine, you have state & props, and the whole frame can be generated from this.  Of course React doesn't clear the whole DOM & re-render everything from scratch, but in a way you can think of it like that.

Comment: yeah got it. thanks everyone for your input. much appreciated.